# MySQL Slave missing table

Tags: mysql

The skip on mysql slave was set very high and it appears to have skipped a table that was created on the master. I've corrected the skip and now the slave has stopped because new data trying to write to the table that is missing on the slave is generating errors. So doing a skip 1 won't work until the slave creates the missing table from the master.

My question is, how do I force the slave to query the master for all the tables/data which it had skipped?  I effectively want something that will compare the differences between master/slave and update the missing information on the slave. Is this possible? Or will I need to do a stop of the master and just rsync everything to the slave (which might take all day for 350Gigs).

Suggestions?

Comment: You set `sql_slave_skip_counter` to a high value?  You are hosed.  Best bet is to rebuild the Slave.

Comment: In addition to the missing table, you have no idea how many other updates to other tables were skipped. If the slave is not the result of **continuous** replication, it's corrupt. Dispose of the slave and reinitialize it using a fresh backup from the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table manually on the slave. This should allow replication to continue, assuming you are using STATEMENT-based replication. There's a chance replication will break again when the slave processes the 'CREATE TABLE' statement, unless you did 'CREATE IF NOT EXISTS'. If replication breaks here, simply skip it and continue on.

If you are using ROW-based replication (to check, on master: SELECT @@binlog_format), you'll have to dump (using mysqldump) or export (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html) the table from the master and copy to the slave. Why? Because ROW-based replication transmits a BEFORE image of the row. If the row doesn't exist, then replication breaks.

Once replication has caught up, you can use pt-table-sync to bring over any other missing data for this one table.